# Ubuntu Pro - audit CIS

Tags: server

I tried to install Ubuntu Pro audit cis_level1_server. I was follow [this article](https://ubuntu.com/blog/cis-security-compliance-usg) but got this error:

[image]

Comment: We are not Canonical employees, and do not provide support for the commercial product named Ubuntu Pro. Support querents or Bug reporters for Ubuntu Pro (individual subscribers) should check https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-client/31027 for the latest support/reporting guidance. Enterprise customers should contact your Sales representative.

Comment: @user535733:  "Questions you may ask": "Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical" are allowed per Ubuntu Help. I would assume Ubuntu Pro is a service of Canonical. Questions about ESM appear to be on-topic. I could be wrong.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron great point. I have raised a [question on AskUbuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20159/are-ubuntu-pro-support-questions-off-topic) to seek clarification on whether this question is on-topic or not.

Comment: As this question is being debated on Meta I have locked it for 7 days to allow this discussion time to resolve and allow full fairness to this question. Link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20159/57576